# Unable to write into Firebase database

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am unable to write data into the real-time database!
I have added the following dependencies inside the pubspec.yaml
Edit: I have added the console log

```
dependencies:
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.0
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  firebase_database: ^ 7.0.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
```

I have also added the correct google.json file. ( I have done the authentication ). Firebase database rules for read and write are both set to true.

My code is as follows :

```
class AddItem extends StatelessWidget{
  AddItem({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
   final database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    final location = database.child('/S2.2');
    
    return Scaffold(
        body:Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Product name',
          ),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Expiration Date',
          ),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Current Date',
          ),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Quantity',
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Save'),
          onPressed: () async {
              location.set({'hi'
              });

          },
        ),

      ],

    ),
    );
  }

}
```

THe console reads :

> W/Firestore( 6723): (24.0.1) [WriteStream]: (6db7a1c) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Cloud Firestore API has not been used in project 966701182638 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firestore.googleapis.com/overview?project=966701182638 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry., cause=null}.

Edit:

I have enabled the APIs. and the console no longer shows any errors. I am using the Firebase Realtime Database.
Once I click the 'Save button', a child of 'S2.2' should form from the root, followed by another child of 'hi'. What's wrong?

Edit 2:

After pressing the save button, which sets the data in the database. The console reads :

```
E/flutter (19417): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: LinkedHashSet len:1
```

The console also reads

```
 DatabaseReference.set (package:firebase_database/src/database_reference.dart:72:39)
```

Any help is greatly appreicated

Comment: Please provide a script where you are trying to send the data to firestore or provide the console log otherwise we are not able to help

Comment: The log is telling you exactly which link to click and enable it

Comment: @FransiTsena has a good point: the code you shared only accesses the Realtime Database, while the error message is about Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate. I wrote an answer below in the assumption you *are* calling the Firestore API elsewhere in your code, but let me know if that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Firestore API in your project is completely disabled, which means you can't access it from within your Flutter app or anywhere else.

If you click the link that is in the error message, it takes you to a place in the Google Cloud console where you can enable it. If you don't have permission on the project do this, you'll have to reach out to one of the project administrators.

Comment: Hello, i enabled the API, but I am still unable to send data into the real-time database